# Xamarin android-How to detect deliver event of deliver FCM foreground messages

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, foregroundnotification

I have implemented FCM notifications in Xamarin android app. When foreground notifications delivering it is not calling `OnMessageReceived` event. How can i get the foreground messages deliver event.

Code for sending FCM message using Postman

```
{ 
 "to":"eXj6c43Jueu6pZ7J6nlPJk81plm5UGjNAwzEGDMM2WQa3EBSxJ-85GDn09wqJ6mE4Jq5nkJ1Qdo", 
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "New homework assigned",
 "OrganizationId":"619",
 "click_action":"SISActivity",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "title" : "KG school",
 "bodyText" : "great match!"
 },
 "data" : {
 "OrganizationId":"6166",
 "moduleName":"Homework",
 "bodyText" : "New homework assigned",

}
}
```

Comment: By `not calling OnMessageReceived event`, please follow [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream) to check where is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am answering my question. The issue is that while sending notifications i was having `notification` payload along with `data` , if app in foreground `OnMessageReceived` wont call in this scenario. if you need to call `OnMessageReceived` always don't send `notification` payload, only we need to send `data` message. Thank you

Comment: You have an example of solution? I have the same problem :(